Call member function getStarttime() when null
I have a strange bug then I switched to PHP 8.1 from 7.4.
This is TYPO3 11.5.32
I have a custom ext where I need to use datetime.
When I have a non 0 value in DB - everything is fine!
Otherwise - I have an error:
"Call member function getStarttime() when null"
There is 0 in the database  - in .sql file
starttime int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

Then I debugging this object I have 'NULL'
       /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $starttime;

/**
     * Get start time
     *
     * @return DateTime|null
     */
    public function getStarttime(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->starttime;
    }

    /**
     * Set start time
     *
     * @param DateTime $starttime end time
     */
    public function setStarttime(DateTime $starttime): void
    {
        $this->starttime = $starttime;
    }

In TCA:
 'starttime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'eval' => 'datetime,int',
                'default' => 0,
                'behaviour' => [
                    'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
                ]
            ],
        ],

What's I'm lost in focus?

in getStarttime function use the if statement and handle the case where $starttime is null return null and if it is not null return return $this->starttime;

I don't think this is the solution as it is just a dumb model which should not hold logic. When hydrating the model by TYPO3 this should be taken care of.

Assign the default value from the modal.
/**
 * @var ?DateTime
 */
protected $starttime = null;

